# How Do I select in jquery an input with specific array name?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array of inputs with specific names:

```
<input name="mytags[aa bb]" value="" type="checkbox">
<input name="mytags[dd vv xx]" value="" type="checkbox">
<input name="mytags[abc bb]" value="" type="checkbox">
```

How can I select a specific input by it's name?
Tried

```
jQuery('input[name=mytags["aa bb"]]').attr("checked", true);
```

but it fails with:
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression 'input[name=mytags["aa bb"]]

Comment: `jQuery('input[name="mytags[aa bb]"]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using quotes properly. Also I would recommend you to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

*Use*

```
$('input[name="mytags[aa bb]"]').prop("checked", true);
```

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     alert( jQuery('input[name="mytags[aa bb]"]').val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="mytags[aa bb]" value="aa bb" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

meta character `[` is breaking the selector. You need to escape it:

```
jQuery('input[name="mytags[aa bb]"]').attr("checked", true);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y3x6dwLb/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your quote is invalid so you have correct `quotes`

```
$('input[name="mytags[aa bb]"]').attr("checked", true);
```

OR

```
$('input[name="mytags[aa bb]"]').prop("checked", true);
```

[Manual for jQuery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)